# Typescript dependency invertion using interfaces

Tags: typescript, class, dependency-injection

I have a class in TypeScript called `UsersUseCases`:

```
import UsersRepository from './UsersRepository';

class UsersUseCases{
    private userRepository:IUsersRepository;

    constructor(receivedUsersRepository:any = null){
        this.userRepository =
            receivedUsersRepository === null ? new UsersRepository() : new receivedUsersRepository();
   }

   /** other methods **/
}
```

My goal here is to use **Dependency Injection** on the `userRepository` at the same time I define a default repository to be used. In that way, I don't need to pass a `receivedUsersRepository` when running the code for real, but only on my tests. Is there a better way to do it?

The code of `IUsersRepository`:

```
export interface IUsersRepository {
    createUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any>;
}
```

The code of `UsersRepository`:

```
class UsersRepository implements IUsersRepository {  
    async createUser(email: string, password: string) {
        /** Implementation **/
    }
}

export default UsersRepository;
```

I've tried the following code:

```
import UsersRepository from './UsersRepository';

class UsersUseCases{
    private userRepository:IUsersRepository;

    constructor(ReceivedUsersRepository: IUsersRepository | null = null) {
        this.userRepository =
        ReceivedUsersRepository === null ? new UsersRepository() : new ReceivedUsersRepository();
    }

   /** other methods **/
}
```

But I've got the following error:

> This expression is not constructable. Type 'IUsersRepository' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)

Sorry for my English. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: There are a difference between UsersRepository and ReceivedUsersRepository?

Comment: Yes. The ReceivedUsersRepository is a mocking implementation.

Comment: If your goal is dependency injection, you should be passing in an already constructed instance of the repository object. You shouldn't be constructing it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about how to resolve your error (and not primarily about dependency injection) then you should learn about [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  The `receivedUsersRepository` parameter is either `null`, or it is a no-arg constructor that produces `IUsersRepository` instances.  It is not itself an `IUsersRepository` instance.  So instead of `IUsersRepository | null`, you should write it like this:

```
receivedUsersRepository: (new () => IUsersRepository) | null
```

And then your code will work as desired:

```
constructor(receivedUsersRepository: (new () => IUsersRepository) | null) {
    this.userRepository =
        receivedUsersRepository === null ?
            new UsersRepository() : new receivedUsersRepository(); // okay
}
```

Hooray.

---

Of course, [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection) means that you are always passing in the `IUsersRepository`, even when running the code for real.  It's an external service.  And you definitely wouldn't be *constructing* that service  in your class.  So to do "real" dependency injection would look more like

```
class UsersUseCases {
    constructor(private userRepositoryService: IUsersRepository) { }
    /** other methods **/
}
```

And then your test code could look like

```
const mockUsersRepository = {
    async createUser(email: string, password: string) {
        console.log("I'M NOT REALLY DOING IT");
    }
}
const testUsersUseCases = new UsersUseCases(mockUsersRepository);
```

while your real code would look like

```
const userRepo = new UsersRepository();
const usersUseCases = new UsersUseCases(userRepo);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOF4IMKQTA3gWAChpjpgB7AOwgBckBXYaspACgAckBLANzGoWh1ESAEoI2ZCJyZIAngGVk3TsAQAuaAEk0KMRKkzZASmg5oAX0IloAegBUd6GWoALZNAC2CV2QAmMBxtCSwJCTgp+JAAzMFUtHQg9SWlmWVMrEmAkBD4EHRYEDzBOEA0aLgoAcwAaaDZICAB3Zl8y2nDKow0ABSQyD05EAB4wClkAPgBuYMJCUAa4YUTxZMNoTg82EEKECJhtJaSDVPSiEkhZCmBSbNz8wuLS6HKO2vqoZqRW5-aqk3wztZiPZHJpNtsvBE+JxKNBAhliCEQnNKDRPGRgABrBJHFJyaAAXlO1guVxuOX49yKJTaFRqdQan2+Lz+xKBxHIVDI2wAdCAyJUWAAiTQAcgAstAAHIAeQAKtARABRACCABk1QBNaAAERlmilAHEtHKhUZpoCLDNQgQbDZoPw0eRfAIUVRqA7sNQEmhMIgYESKAhGotkKhEH7sCwPBjsYcVsc5ObZja7dBbiBSH4EG60UJkElCdAgyGcQm8bIWMmCJy80tfVgA8Xg6GUA3-Sx86IVuagA)